# I selected "manually release this version" - what next?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I submitted an app to itunes connect. As I remember, I selected the aforementioned field instead of the other one with automatic release. Now my app status is ready to sale, what should I do next? Where should I "manually release" it? I can't see such option in itunes connect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh, I guess this is all about setting date of release right? There's no such button "release" or something?

Comment: You may want to move this to SO.